# How to exclude parameters from MongoDB document in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a customers data base which includes several parameters (example 1) and I want to build a method that gets list of id's (or ObjectId id's) and list of parameters and to return only the customers that their id located in the received list, but, I don't want to return the entire customer parameters but only those that located in the received field list. I have found online many examples but none of them does not answer my needs..
Since I do not know how many parameters my list contains I think the best way to do so is to exclude the parameters that does not appear in the received list.
So far I did not managed to operate any code.

Example of a customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public ObjectId id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Emails { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

Examples of parameters list that the method can recieve:

```
List<string> fields1 = {"FirstName", "LastName"};
List<string> fields2 = {"LastName", "FirstName", "Picture"};
List<string> fields3 = {"Emails", "Phones"};
```

Example of id's list that the method can receive:

```
    List<string> id1 = {"241251235"};
    List<string> id2 = {"241251235", "12542134", "1231245123"};
```

Basically, the desired output for fields1 and id1 is a query of: Select FirstName, LastName where id == id1[0];
(But since I do not know how many id's and parameters I get - it is where it goes complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $in

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
public async Task DeleteUnicityAsync(IMongoCollection<uid> collection, List<int> uids)
{
    await collection.DeleteManyAsync(Builders<uid>.Filter.In(_ => _._id, uids));
}
```

A full example here

https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/03%20-%20Expert/BatchUnicity.cs